# How to Duplicate an AppleScript function in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, applescript

This AppleScript code gives the name of files that have been dropped onto the script. How do I do the same in an Objective-C app? Would an application written in Objective-C be able to boot the JAR file using the file name as an argument to JAR?

```
on open of theFiles -- Executed when files are dropped on the script

    set fileCount to (get count of items in theFiles)

    repeat with thisFile from 1 to fileCount
        set theFile to item thisFile of theFiles
        set theFileAlias to theFile as alias

        tell application "Finder"
                set fileInfo to info for theFileAlias
                set fileName to name of fileInfo

                -- something to this effect, but now that you have the file name,
                -- do what you will...
                do shell script "cd /Desktop/RunJar/; java -jar " & fileName

        end tell

    end repeat

end open
```

We need to replace this AppleScript with a compiled app that can run a JAR that has been dropped onto the compiled app.

Answer (score 2):

To get the path to the JAR file, your app must first implement Drag-and-Drop. [See Drag and Drop Programing Topics for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html)  (or as [PDF](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.pdf))

Comment: 1) An answer that consists solely of a link is generally considered bad practice. Stack Overflow aims to become _the_ repository of answers for _all_ questions, so if you link, copy some relevant quotes from the link and maybe elaborate. 2) If you do link to documentation (which isn't a bad thing in and of itself), don't use the term "RTFM," as it is very condescending and will turn a lot of people off. That's no way to help people out, is it?

Comment: Is this policy documented somewhere?  The answers to questions go out of date.  I'd much rather link to docs owned by a project when applicable.  Furthermore, when people attempt to restate docs, they often make mistakes that aren't in the original.

Comment: @Ken: And links die in time, too. It's much better for someone to find outdated content than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As for actually running the jar:

> do shell script "cd /Desktop/RunJar/; java -jar " & fileName

Use [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/). The difference is that NSTask does not run a shell script; it runs the program (in this case, `java`) directly. You will need to set the task's working directory before running it.